# Server side printing in PHP 5

Tags: php, html, printing, server-side

How can i print my html file via php script? I just want to run it in background without any prompt. I have read other posts regarding this but still didnt find anything working.
I tried this one :

```
<?php
$dir = "temp"; // the folder that you are storing the file to be printed
$file = "file.html"; //change to proper file name
$file_dir = $dir.$file;
$server = "home_computer"; //name of the computer you are printing to on your network
$printer = "HP"; //printers shared name
$command = "print $file_dir /d:\\$server\\$printer";
exec($command) or die("File failed to print");
?>
```

got this example here http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php/topic,207946.0.html

Comment: @Smamatti these functions are older than Chuck Norris. No offense Chuck.

Comment: This is true, but I didn't find any newer versions, they should be working and they aren't marked as deprecated. So what is  your point?

Comment: that's for winblows. for normal OS, you need to use exec functions to run `lpr`, for example...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is what i got working :

```
$html = "testing print";
$handle = printer_open();
printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW");
printer_write($handle, $html);
printer_close($handle);
```

We require **php_printer.dll** php extension to make this work in php5. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't print html pages with php.  Php is a server-side language, it runs on the server.

The printer is on the client's machine. Meaning you'll need a client-side language to accomplish this.

Comment: Maybe he wants to print something at the server on specific client actions?

Comment: I have to do this on the same machine where the script resides.

Comment: @salman what exactly are you trying to do? You want the html page to print on the client our in the server? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to run it on my localhost only.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the source code then it should be be doable by writing a program that prints the passed string and then calling it via a system call. On windows it appears to have an extension for that.

If you want to print a rendered version, then you have to know that for that you need some kind of a rendering engine. While not impossible its probably more work than what you want to get into.