# Printing to a Thermal Receipt Printer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, sql

Does anyone have any easy way I can print a bill using data from my Db via Jquery and php without browser prompting the user to select printer or anything.

Comment: How do you know there is a thermal printer?  What do you do if there are multiple thermal printers?  Why can't you just print to the default printer?  Why can't you ask the user to configure the printer to use once, and then store that configuration?  Computers aren't psychic....

Comment: There are many duplicates, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/10810521, https://stackoverflow.com/q/28685932, https://stackoverflow.com/q/2012936, https://stackoverflow.com/q/11168116. To get more specific help, you should try to write some code based on any of these questions and ask a specific question about the code you've written, if you encounter any further problems.